# logarithmic transformation from exponential to linear equation

Tags: logarithms, linear-transformations, transformation

How to convert this exponential equation to linear equation.

$Y =\exp(17.9348)\cdot x^{-2.705}$

what I did is:
$Y =\log(17.9348)-2.705\log(x).$

I am confused with this one: 
$Y=17.9348-2.705\log(x).$

Which one is correct transformation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is neither! You need to take the logarithm of *both sides:*
\begin{align*}
y&=e^{17.9348}\,x^{-2.705} \\
\ln(y)&=\ln\left(e^{17.9348}\,x^{-2.705}\right) \\
\ln(y)&=\ln\left(e^{17.9348}\right)+\ln\left(x^{-2.705}\right) \\
\ln(y)&=17.9348-2.705\ln(x).
\end{align*}

Comment: ok, thank you so much!